# Convert one timezone to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset, moment-timezone

I'm looking for a function that receives a time, source timezone 
and a destination
and returns time in the destination timezone

timezones are in the following format:
'utc', 'est', 'edt', 'gmt', ...

```
function convertTime(time,fromZone,toZone){
   // do conversion
   return convertedTime;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use a moment.js library.

Comment: @HirasawaYui I know moment but couldn't find how to do what I'm looking for with moment and i see timezones in moment are in this format
for example "America/New_York" and not "est"

Comment: @user4092086—you could create your own map of abbreviations to IANA representative locations, however you need a strategy for dealing with ambiguous abbreviations (such as EST and CST). Also, different places in a timezone may have different rules for daylight saving, hence IANA's choice of representative locations rather than the broader timezone designators (though the concept of "timezone" is changing to align with IANA's approach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but it is not possible to convert between time zones in the way you describe, for several reasons:

- Many time zone abbreviations are ambiguous.  For example, `CST` could be Central Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time, or China Standard Time.  `IST` could be India Standard Time, Israel Standard Time, or Irish Summer Time.  There are many other examples.
- Not everyone agrees on what the abbreviations for time zones should be.  For example, in Hawaii, both `HST` and `HAST` are commonly used.
- Not all time zone abbreviations are in English.  For example, `HNE` and `HAE` are French time zones abbreviations used for the Eastern time zone in Canada.
- Not all time zones *have* abbreviations in the way we think about them.  For example, there are two time zones in Kazakhstan.  In the western part of the country they are 5 hours ahead of UTC.  In the eastern part of the country they are 6 hours ahead of UTC.  In the past, English speakers have assigned made-up abbreviations such as `AQTT` or `ORAT` to the west, and `ALMT` to the east, after the names of some major cities, but none of those are actually used there nor ever have been.
- Assuming `EST` and `EDT` are Eastern Standard Time and Eastern Daylight Time as observed in the US and Canada, you would have to predetermine whether to pass `EST` or `EDT` to your function depending on which was in effect at the time given.  For example, if you passed a time on today, 2013-03-13 and used `EST`, you would be in error since `EDT` is currently in effect.  This would apply for both `fromZone` and `toZone`, and each would have to be determined independently.
- Say you tried to write logic to address the previous point.  You would still have problems where two different time zone abbreviations apply to different parts of the same time zone at the same time.  For example, right now `MDT` applies to most of the US Mountain time zone - except most (but not all) of Arizona where `MST` applies.

All of the above factors and more are considered by using [IANA tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) identifiers, such as `America/New_York`, instead of abbreviations.

I also suggest reviewing the following resources:

- [The timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) here on Stack Overflow
- The YouTube video [*The Problem with Time & Timezones*](https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY) by Computerphile
- The article [*Time Zone Abbreviations*](https://codeofmatt.com/time-zone-abbreviations/) on my blog

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good StackOverflow past-post about this general subject:

[How to initialize a JavaScript Date to a particular time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone#15171030)

Comment: Hi.  Link-only answers are discouraged here. Also the question you link to is about initializing `Date` objects, not converting values between time zones.